# Placing a scrollable div below a fixed div of variable height

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

This is with respect to a mobile page in jquery mobile

I have 2 divs as follows within a parent div(data-role=header)

```
<div data-role="header">
<div class="inner-topHeader-panel"></div>
<div class="inner-centercontent"></div>
</div>
```

I want "inner-topHeader-panel" to be a fixed in position(note: it is of variable height) and "inner-centercontent" to be placed below "inner-topHeader-panel" and be scrollable. When scrolled, parts of it that is scrolled up should be hidden behind the "inner-topHeader-panel" div.

Current CSS is as follows.

```
.inner-topHeader-panel{ 
    width:100%; 
    height:auto; 
    margin:0; 
    background:#fff; 
    border-bottom:none;
    float:left;
    position:fixed !important; 
    top:0;
}

.inner-centercontent{
  width:100%;
float:left;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 }
```

solution:
Thanks @LessQuesar,@ezanker and @mainguy, I set second div's css as follows and it worked!

```
.inner-centercontent{ 
width:100%; 
height:100px;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
float:left;  
position:fixed !important;  
padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

and i set the .inner-centercontent's top position using jQuery according to the height of .inner-topHeader-panel

Comment: Fixed elements don't take up vertical space. If you really need the effect of the content going underneath, you'll need some JS to fix the 2nd div's top padding according to the height of the first div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
.inner-topHeader-panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 20;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: none;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.inner-centercontent {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zj4wgjGB7VMjAYFax1D9?p=preview)

Will only scroll when height is smaller than inner content.

Answer (score 2):

On `pageshow`, calculate the height of the fixed div and set the `margin-top` of the div below it to that value:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#page1", function(){
    var fixedH = $(".inner-topHeader-panel").outerHeight(true);
    $(".inner-centercontent").css("margin-top", fixedH + "px");
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3w5dt/)**