# CSS Flexbox with multiple scrollable regions

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a flexbox which has a header and then a left pane (scrollable) and right pane (scrollable). They need to be able to scroll separate from each other. Most importantly the parent frame must take up exactly 100% of the width and height.

Below is an image of what I am trying to achieve

[image: Visual Representation of what I want to achieve]

I also have a snippet that I have tried so far.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdJgBN?editors=110

I can fudge it and not use flexbox but it seems like a waste not to use it when I'm so close (the separate scrollable regions and sticky header don't work currently).

```css
body {
    font: caption;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/**
 * The main flex container
 */
div.flex-main-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/**
 * The fixed header
 */
div.flex-header {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}

/**
 * The container under header to hold the 2 rows
 */
div.flex-content {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

/**
 * Left flex container
 */
div.flex-files {
    flex: 3;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #00DD00;
}

/**
 * Right flex container
 */
div.flex-insert {
    flex: 7;
    background-color: #00FFDD;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="flex-main-container">
  <div class="flex-header">
   Header content here<br/>
   Header content here<br/>
   Header content here<br/>
   Header content here<br/>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-content">
   <div class="flex-files">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sed lacus felis. Suspendisse euismod neque eu est consequat facilisis. Fusce efficitur est sem, nec posuere neque iaculis quis. Curabitur euismod massa sit amet mauris porttitor, vel vulputate ipsum vehicula. Nulla ut erat ut leo mollis mattis at sit amet urna. Nam condimentum a lectus in lacinia. Suspendisse at diam non felis lobortis placerat. Donec faucibus non arcu vel fringilla. Mauris nec porta dolor, at hendrerit justo. Phasellus ut est maximus nulla efficitur malesuada consequat eu felis. Etiam et ipsum in tellus vestibulum ornare feugiat in augue. Vestibulum luctus erat a nulla sollicitudin auctor. Integer erat leo, semper in tempor ac, elementum ac sapien.</p>

             <p>Nunc dignissim tristique nisi eu consequat. Curabitur ornare ornare nunc a condimentum. Mauris tempus nisl sit amet nunc feugiat, sit amet ullamcorper tortor faucibus. Curabitur nisl leo, porta luctus leo sit amet, lobortis sodales lectus. Quisque fringilla at nunc quis sodales. Phasellus eget dapibus velit, nec aliquam sem. Nam a nisl ex. Morbi quis faucibus nisi. Curabitur fermentum porttitor orci eget venenatis. Phasellus ac dui eros. Maecenas sodales, justo non dignissim pharetra, libero sapien scelerisque magna, ultrices viverra sem libero nec nisl. Curabitur a nisi porttitor, eleifend mi imperdiet, vehicula quam. Donec porta nibh nec semper tempor.</p>

             <p>Nam elementum sem non turpis dictum, ut placerat nunc posuere. Duis sed nisl at leo tempor hendrerit vitae et enim. Quisque vel urna sed quam convallis rhoncus vitae nec nibh. Ut a nibh id eros interdum consequat. Nulla efficitur at libero nec ultrices. Ut ut lectus sit amet arcu molestie viverra. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque venenatis elit sodales ultricies sodales. Ut tempus auctor est in bibendum. Proin enim ipsum, venenatis vel blandit et, dictum in massa. Donec augue purus, egestas sed enim et, pretium gravida diam. Morbi tincidunt cursus augue id condimentum. Mauris congue libero turpis, quis laoreet augue gravida nec.</p>

             <p>Nullam fermentum laoreet ipsum sit amet egestas. Maecenas non diam eget nisi faucibus sollicitudin. Sed semper ipsum sit amet arcu pulvinar, eget rhoncus nunc egestas. Proin aliquet faucibus purus, in aliquam urna posuere at. Duis fringilla at magna ac condimentum. Fusce eu nibh orci. Praesent dictum facilisis eros, non tincidunt sem ullamcorper in.</p>

             <!-- <p>Vestibulum at volutpat nibh. Nam semper at tortor ut tempus. Nunc bibendum urna sit amet quam suscipit tempus. Curabitur facilisis sagittis efficitur. Etiam ultrices nulla vel leo dictum posuere. Ut sed erat sed velit vehicula porta. Proin sagittis pulvinar lacus et sodales. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aenean congue lobortis erat nec malesuada.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sed lacus felis. Suspendisse euismod neque eu est consequat facilisis. Fusce efficitur est sem, nec posuere neque iaculis quis. Curabitur euismod massa sit amet mauris porttitor, vel vulputate ipsum vehicula. Nulla ut erat ut leo mollis mattis at sit amet urna. Nam condimentum a lectus in lacinia. Suspendisse at diam non felis lobortis placerat. Donec faucibus non arcu vel fringilla. Mauris nec porta dolor, at hendrerit justo. Phasellus ut est maximus nulla efficitur malesuada consequat eu felis. Etiam et ipsum in tellus vestibulum ornare feugiat in augue. Vestibulum luctus erat a nulla sollicitudin auctor. Integer erat leo, semper in tempor ac, elementum ac sapien.</p>

             <p>Nunc dignissim tristique nisi eu consequat. Curabitur ornare ornare nunc a condimentum. Mauris tempus nisl sit amet nunc feugiat, sit amet ullamcorper tortor faucibus. Curabitur nisl leo, porta luctus leo sit amet, lobortis sodales lectus. Quisque fringilla at nunc quis sodales. Phasellus eget dapibus velit, nec aliquam sem. Nam a nisl ex. Morbi quis faucibus nisi. Curabitur fermentum porttitor orci eget venenatis. Phasellus ac dui eros. Maecenas sodales, justo non dignissim pharetra, libero sapien scelerisque magna, ultrices viverra sem libero nec nisl. Curabitur a nisi porttitor, eleifend mi imperdiet, vehicula quam. Donec porta nibh nec semper tempor.</p> -->
   </div>
   <div class="flex-insert">
    Insert data
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="flex-header">
        Header content here
        <br/> Header content here
        <br/> Header content here
        <br/> Header content here
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-main-container">
        <div class="flex-content">
            <div class="flex-files">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-insert">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

*Notes:*

- The fixed header was removed from the flex container. This enables us to position the flex container below the header with CSS.
- Since an element with `position: fixed` is taken out of the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow), and [does not participate in flex layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items) there was no reason for it to exist in the flex container, and removing it is helpful to the overall layout.
- The header, if kept within the flex container, would still have been able to participate in [reordering](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-property) (i.e., use of the flex `order` property), but as a fixed element, the assumption is made that it is unlikely to be re-positioned.

**CSS**

```
html {
  height: 100%; /* full height of viewport */
}

body {
  height: calc(100% - 80px); /* prevent vertical scrollbar on browser; see below */
  font: caption;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.flex-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px; /* height for header; adjustable; can be fixed or relative units */
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

div.flex-main-container {
  /* position: absolute;  <-- Removed. Not necessary. */
  margin-top: 80px; /* compensate for header height */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

div.flex-content {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0; /* addresses FF vertical scroll bug */
  min-width: 0; /* addresses FF vertical scroll bug */
}

div.flex-files {
  flex: 3;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #00DD00;
}

div.flex-insert {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 7;
  background-color: #00FFDD;
}
```

Notes:

- You wrote:

  > Most importantly the parent frame must take up exactly 100% of the width and height.

  This can be done with `html, body { height: 100%; }`. You don't need `position: absolute`.
- The fixed header is given a defined height, which enables the flex container to position itself below the header with a `margin-top` buffer.
- If you don't want a defined height for the header, see here: [Placing a scrollable div below a fixed div of variable height](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21706915/3597276)
- The `min-height: 0` and `min-width: 0` added to `.flex-content` is necessary to address a vertical scroll bug in Firefox. Details here: [Vertical scroll rendering issue in Flexbox in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32911324/3597276)

The adjusted code above renders a fixed header with two scrollable regions:

[image]

Tested on Chrome, Firefox and IE11.

[**Modified Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epxWjQ?editors=110)

Comment: You sir, are a legend. Thanks heaps for this :)